# discord.js v12 checking if a user starts streaming

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This works as intended till it crashes. Every time a users starts streaming, it posts their stream link.
The problem is that after like 5min the bot crashes and i get the error below.

```
let oldStreamingStatus = oldMember.activities.find(activity =>  activity.type  === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined
```

my code below.

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {

let oldStreamingStatus = oldMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
let newStreamingStatus = newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;

if (oldStreamingStatus == newStreamingStatus) {
    return;
}

if (newStreamingStatus) {
    if (newMember.member.roles.cache.some(r => ["Raider","Trial"].includes(r.name))) {
        const activity = newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING')
        // console.log(newMember.activities)
        client.channels.cache.get("731911793257087006").send(`Hey! ${activity.url} is streaming!`);
        return;
    } else
        return;
    }});
```

I tried this code below. But it posts another message if someone changes their activity or if they are currently STREAMING and then start LISTENING to Spotify.

```
  client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {

  if (!newPresence.activities) return false;

  newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
    if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
        console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
       };
        });
   });
```

Seems like i need 10 reputation to post the pictures in the right way. I do apologize for that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you please the code in your question, instead of images?

Comment: I do apologize for the look of it. I really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we will follow the discord.js documentation we can see that 'oldMember' is optional:

[image]

And exception message says:

> Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined

Add additional check :

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(!oldMember){
        //skip actions or get streaming status based only on newMember activities...
    }
```

before the rest of your code.